# How to assert FK is not null using it's id with mypy

Tags: python, django, django-models, mypy, typing

I have a couple models:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
  district = models.ForeignKey(
        District,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=None,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
  )

class District(models.Model):
   timezone = TimeZoneField(default="US/Eastern")
```

And I'm trying to write a function that will get the timezone for a user.

I tried this:

```
def get_timezone_for_user(user: MyUser) -> datetime.timezone:
    if not user.district_id:
        return DEFAULT_TIMEZONE

    return user.district.timezone
```

But `mypy` doesn't like this because it thinks `user.district` can still be `None`, even though I know it cannot because the existence of `district_id` means that user.district is also not None.

I can add an `assert user.district is not None` in there, but then I will incur an extra query just to persuade `mypy`. Any ideas that don't involve adding an additional query?

Comment: Never mind I realized that this doesn't actually incur an extra query. The second time you lookup district it is cached automatically by django.

Comment: Even if it were an extra query, couldn't use just change your first test to `if user.district is None: return DEFAULT_TIMEZONE`? `user.district_id` just seems like a proxy for what you *really* want to test.

Answer (score 0):

You already perform that extra SQL query in your `return` statement, so this approach should execute the same number of SQL statements. If `user.district_id` is `None` the ORM won't attempt to `SELECT` it anyway:

```py
def get_timezone_for_user(user: MyUser) -> datetime.timezone:
    district = user.district
    if not district:
        return district.timezone

    return district.timezone
```